# Linq Group by and get all values for a specific string rule returning all columns

Tags: c#, list, linq, filtering, grouping

I'm facing a problem so I'll give all context.

I'm getting 2 exams from a generic list of strings, each one have the same Email and a Passed Yes or No.

How Am I getting?

`var list = new List<string>();`

For each string I'm getting a record that is between position 0 and 13 to a model, works fine

```
List<Participants> p = new List<Participants>();
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 13)
{
    p.Add(new Participants()
    {
        LastName = list[0 + i],
        FirstName = list[1 + i],
        AddressType = list[2 + i],
        Email = list[3 + i],
        Company = list[4 + i],
        Phone = list[5 + i],
        Street = list[6 + i],
        ZipCode = list[7 + i],
        City = list[8 + i],
        IsSiemens = isSiemens,
        Country = list[9 + i],
        Percent = list[10 + i],
        Points = list[11 + i],
        Passed = list[12 + i],
    });
}
```

Then this works since I know I had only 2 parts (Exams)

```
var distinctList = p.GroupBy(s => s.Email).Select(s => s.First()).ToList();

var distinctList = p.GroupBy(s => s.Email).Select(s => s.Last()).ToList();
```

The problem now is I can have more exams, I want to do it dynamically, so for each Email I want to be able to know if passed all or not. In another words Grouping the model by `Email` all `Passed` must be yes, then I know for this Certification that specific Email completed with success.

I'm blocked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In another words Grouping the model by Email all Passed must be yes, then I know for this Certification that specific Email completed with success.

Sounds like, at its most basic

```
var listOfEmailsThatPassed = p
  .GroupBy(s => s.Email)
  .Where(g => g.All(pt => pt.Passed == "Yes"))
  .Select(g => g.Key)
  .ToList()
```

You didn't say what type Passed is; i assumed string but if it's a bool `g.All(pt => pt.Passed)`.

Grouping can be tricky to get your head round, but think of it like a list-of-list-of-participant, you have a `.Where(` that acts on a grouping `g`, which is a list of participants, so you want `All` the participants `pt` in the grouping to have passed

For a list of participants (I've skipped detail like the course name):

```
   john@a.com Yes
   john@a.com Yes
   fred@b.com Yes
   fred@b.com No
```

After grouping it looks like

```
   g => g.Key: john@a.com   g: [ john@a.com Yes, john@a.com Yes] 
   g => g.Key: fred@b.com   g: [ fred@b.com Yes, fred@b.com No]
```

So you can use Where to act on each of these two rows, and `g` is itself a (sub)list of Participants that all share the same Key (email), so you ask that `g.All(participant => some predicate)`.. and that's where you test that `Passed == "Yes"` as your predicate. If anyone is `Passed == "No"` then the `All` will return `false` and the `Where` will exclude them from the results

After Where'ing it looks like:

```
   g => g.Key: john@a.com   g: [ john@a.com Yes, john@a.com Yes]
```

It's still a grouping, so perhaps you have to select the email:

```
.Select(g => g.Key).ToList()
```

this will churn out a `List<string>` of the emails that passed

Comment: Good point, I can put this work but I need the entire model, so I have to repeat the `foreach` in the  `list` putting a flag if contains filtered `List<string>`. Is working but to be honest the code is really bad. I can put the solution but will give a really bad reputation :)

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. When you "need the entire model" what does it mean? There is no `foreach` in my code.. are you saying you don't want a list of string, you want a list of Participant?

Comment: Yes, exactly a List of type Participants